# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm trying out very simple tutorial on how to send e-mail via `.NET` and `C#`. However when I try to execute the code I got the following exception:

> **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll Additional information: The operation has timed
>   out.**

So what I have done is to find the server settings to which I want to send mails to. This is very popular in my country:

```
Incoming settings

Protocol -> POP
Email address -> username@abv.bg
Username -> username@abv.bg
Password -> password
POP server -> pop3.abv.bg
Security type -> SSL
Server port -> 995

Outgoing server settings

Username -> username@abv.bg
Password -> password
SMTP server -> smtp.abv.bg
Security type -> SSL
Server port -> 465
```

then I created a `Console project` and in my main method I have this code:

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.abv.bg");
        client.Port = 465;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 100000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
         "username@abv.bg", "password");

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add("username@abv.bg");
        msg.From = new MailAddress("username@abv.bg");
        msg.Subject = "Test subject";
        msg.Body = "Test test test...";
        client.Send(msg);
```

Since I have no experience with this I just try the code as you see it. No additional settings anywhere. The only thing that I think should not be problem but I think worth mentioning that here:

```
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
         "username@abv.bg", "password");
```

and here:

```
         msg.To.Add("username@abv.bg");
```

I'm using the same e-mail. But I think this shouldn't be a problem. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example (with Gmail) I wrote years ago for testing.

```
public  void sendEmail(string body)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                return;
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(email);
                mail.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("yyy@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "sub";

                mail.Body = body;

                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                     ("yyy@gmail.com", "pw"); // ***use valid credentials***
                smtp.Port = 587;

                //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                print("Exception in sendEmail:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I would try this function with Gmail just to eliminate network related issues like firewall. When that will work, the rest is just to find the right settigs for the SMPT server

Comment: In fact my first try was with gmail but even with your code I get this error - `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.` I've read a bit about it and it seems that I have to explicitly allow receiving mails from or something else.. I forgot. But I thought that the Gmail is the exception so I tried different email client.

Comment: Did you change pw to your actual password @Leron?

Comment: Yeap, I'm using my real password. I'm aware that here password is just substitute. In google security I get message for `Unusual Activity` which is saying that someone tried to sign up (me trying the code) and that this someone knows my password, so yes - it's the real one.

Comment: Yes. You need to enable it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en

Comment: Look for that email in your inbox: "Google Account: sign-in attempt blocked".

Comment: Yeap, after changing the security settings I was able to sent e-mail. However this is just g-mail, what if I want to send to whatever else mail provider?

Comment: Ahaa, so I have to use one e-mail as say - base(sender) and I can send to different e-mail providers.. hmm. Interesting. I'm gonna accept your answer.